# Validate that a password is alphanumeric with regex JS

Tags: javascript

I want to validate that an entered password contains letters (no minimum or maximum) and at least 1 number. Ths is my validation so far.

```
function validate(){

var password = $("#password").val(); //user enters password in text field

if (/^[0-9]{1,}[A-Za-z]{1,}/.test(password)){ //this regex does not quite do what i want
    alert("Password is correct");
}
else if (password == null || password.length == 0){
    alert("Enter password");
}else{
    alert("Wrong password");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex for alphanumeric characters:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

Regex for at least one numeric:

```
/\d/
```

Regex for at least one alphabetic:

```
/[A-Z]/i
```

You can combine the above into an if statement as follows:

```
if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(password) && /\d/.test(password) &&
    /[A-Z]/i.test(password)) {
    alert("Password is correct");
}
```

Comment: That matches 'A' and '9'.  The requirement was for at least one of each.

Comment: 'A' won't satisfy /\d/ and '9' won't satisfy /[A-Z]/i

Comment: Ah, yes.  But 3 regex's aren't necessary in a world with positive lookahead assertions.

Answer (score 2):

Try `/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)/i`

(Play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/qJ7vS9/1)